# Selenium/ChromeDriver Error when running in Headless Mode using VSCode: (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When I try to use Python3, Selenium & ChromeDriver to launch a **non-headless** Chrome browser instance (from **VSCode's Terminal**)

```py
from chromedriver_py import binary_path 
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=binary_path)
driver.get('http://google.com')
driver.close()
```

this will throw the error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

The only way I get avoid the error is to run in headless mode:

```py
from chromedriver_py import binary_path  
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=binary_path, options=options)
x = driver.get('http://google.com')
driver.close()
```

Why does it not work unless it is in headless mode? Both code works when not running using Vscode's Terminal. How can it run it non-headless from within Vscode?

---

Using `chromedriver-py==88.0.4324.96` & `selenium==3.141.0` on Ubuntu 20.04. Python file is executed using VSCode.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WebDriverException: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist while trying to initiate Chrome Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642308/webdriverexception-unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-doesnt-exist-while-t)

Comment: @Cyrus Thanks, clarified that my question is using VSCode's Terminal to launch the Pytho script. Everything works as expected when not using VSCode to execute the Python code.

Comment: Perhaps your script is inheriting improper permissions from VS Code. Do you run your script as super user when you run it from the terminal?

Comment: @Cryus I am running the script as a non-root user, both in VSCode which gave the error, as well as in a regular terminal which does not give the error